# How to persist an IPropertyBag to disk

Tags: c++, winapi, persist, propertybag

I've successfully obtained an `IPropertyBag` for the view state of a folder.  I obtained it using `SHGetViewStatePropertyBag`, and I've confirmed that the bag is valid by checking some property values.

What I'd like to do now is persist the property bag to disk as a blob, if possible.  I've been running `QueryInterface` on the bag, and I haven't been able to obtain any helpful interfaces.  Unfortunately, it appears that the property bag doesn't support an `IPersistStream` interface.  And I haven't been able to successfully query the `IPersistPropertyBag` interface either.

Is there a trick to getting some sort of persist interface for a property bag?  Or do the properties essentially have to be saved individually, in an ad hoc manner?  Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: If there's no persist interface, or if IPropertBag2::Write is not implemented, it means it's a read-only bag (the Shell doesn't want you to do that and break its things). I don't know of any builtin IPersistPropertyBag(2) implementation that we can reuse. So, you'll have to enumerate properties and save/read them the way you like.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much.

Comment: How about IPersistStreamInit? It's very similar to IPersistStream but does not actually derive from IPersistStream. And if all else fails you might query for IProvideClassInfo and write out the ITypeInfo (I know this would be a PITA but if implemented it will likely give you a much better idea of what interfaces are actually available).

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Thanks, but `IPersistStreamInit` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Write` on the `IPropertyBag` should write the change to disk automagically.

In general, IPersistXXX interface is implemented by objects that can save themselves into an XXX (where XXX is either Stream or PropertyBag), meanwhile `IPropertyBag` and `IStream` are expected to be backed by something - a disk, or a memory block, or a socket.

Or do want to take all properties from the bag *and somehow save them elsewhere*? In that case, you'd want to query for `IPropertyBag2` and enumerate them.

Comment: Yes, to clarify, I meant I wanted to save the bag elsewhere, ideally as just a blob.  I should have clarified.  And unfornately, `IPropertyBag2` is not implemented by the bag.  I think you can obtain the interface, but the methods aren't implemented.

Comment: What's the larger context? What are you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: I'm trying to implement a feature that allows the user to save the current folder layout (columns, sort order, etc.) by name, and then apply that layout to other folders as desired.

Comment: What I'd pursue instead, get a `IShellFolder` or `IShelLFolderView`, see if one of *those* supports `IPersistPropertyBag`, implement your own `IPropertyBag` and tell the folder object to save to *that*.

Comment: I'm trying that method.  Do you know how to create an empty property bag for use with `IPersistPropertyBag`?

Comment: Implement your own. `class MyPropertyBag: public IPropertyBag { /* and so forth */ };`